# Play framework: directory listing

Tags: directory, playframework-2.3, directory-listing

What is the quickest way of [listing/serving files] outside of Play's **public** folder using the Play framework (2.3) ?

I am looking for something similar to the Directory Listing available in Apache. A simple web page that allows me to securely navigate a predefined directory and its sub-directories.

Is there anything readily available that does this?

Comment: By definition, everything outside your `public` directory is not public... If you don't need specific features, use your webserver to do it (Apache, Nginx...). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Sorry, no quick way to do that...